# Why is Excel Number Format still showing decimal place despite my Conditional Formula?

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting

I'm trying to format my table such that only numbers with a decimal value greater than 0.1 show up with a decimal place. So for e.g. for the number 2.00625, I only want this to show up as "2" not "2.0". However, for everything else, I'd like the number format to be one decimal place -- so for 0.725, I'd like "0.7"

[image: My Table]

I've written a conditional format formula using MOD, but it doesn't seem to work on one value and I can't figure out why. Can someone please help me figure this out.

[image: My Conditional Format]

Comment: I don't understand where `160` comes from in `MOD(C3,160)`. To check the fractional part, you need `MOD(C3,1)`.

Comment: Oops. My bad. The 160 represents work hours in a month. So I meant to do `MOD(C3/160,1)` -- I just did that, but I still get the same result.

Comment: I'll make some checks later, but now I need to go out for the evening. It may be tomorrow before I can let you know what I find.

Comment: Sounds good. Thanks, AFH. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried applying the conditional formula as `=MOD(C5,1)<0.1` to cells C5:K6? It looks like `C5` already has a formula of `=C3/160`.

Comment: I have done some tests and all seems to be working as expected, but your formula for the cell in question seems wrong: surely it should be `=MOD(G3/160,1)<0.1` or more simply `=MOD(G5,1)<0.1`? If you are applying the formula to the selected numeric elements in the row `C5:N5` then you need to specify `=MOD(C3/160,1)<0.1` or `=MOD(C5,1)<0.1`. I recreated your table with `C5:N5` set to `C3:N3` divided by 160 and used `=MOD(C5,1)<0.1` in the conditional format for the selected elements, and the formatting was as you wanted. I think you may be applying the condition to the wrong cell(s).